# SSRS Boolean Parameter With Multiple True Returns

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

Here is a filter expression that successfully returns the value of 6 if the boolean parameter is set to true.  However, I'm needing it to return both a 6 and a 3 if True.

```
=IIF(parameters!Maintenance.Value = Cbool("True"), 6, fields!Group_I.Value)
```

Comment: IIF is a scalar function and can only have one return value.  You can create a separate expression that will return 3.

Comment: Are you using this in an `IN` filter? Something else?

Comment: Yes.  I am using the IN Operator on the Expression Group_I.  
I tried to create a separate expression, the same as the first, that returned a 3 instead of a 6 but the report now returns nothing.  I believe they conflicted with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

In your filter Expression, do something like this:

```
=Switch(Fields!Group_I.Value = 3, "Maintenance",
    Fields!Group_I.Value = 6, "Maintenance",
    True,"Other")
```

Use `=` for the Operator.

And use this for the Value expression:

```
=IIf(Parameters!Maintenance.Value = True, "Maintenance", "Other")
```

You may have to play around with the field names in the code above.

This will limit what is displayed in the table based on the value in the `Fields!Group_I.Value`. In the first expression you map the value to "Maintenance" if it is either 3 or 6, otherwise it goes to "Other". Then the second expression sets the filter values based on the parameter.

Hope this helps you out.